# Length of the path of the car for the time interval $[0,25]$

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

The linear function $a$ describes in dependence of the time $t$ the acceleration $a(t)$ of a car (t in s, a(t) in m/$s^2$).

The acceleration has the value $0\ m/s^2$ for $t=0$ and the value $2.4\ m/s^2$ for $t=25$.

(a) Determine the equation of the function $a$.

The speed of that car at time $t=0$ is $0\ m/s$.

(b) Calculate the length of the path of the car for the time interval $[0,25]$.

$$$$

For (a) I have done the following :

The function is linear so it is of the form $a(t)=kt+d$.

Using the values $a(0)=0$ and $a(25)=2.4$ we get $a(t)=0.096t$.

For (b) I have done the following so far :

$$v(t)=\int a\, dt=0.048t^2+c$$ Since $v(0)=0$ we get $c=0$and so $$v(t)=\int a\, dt=0.048t^2$$
The we have that $$s(t)=\int v(t)\, dt=0.016t^3+c$$ Is that correct so far? How can we calculate the constant here?

Comment: You can assume that the car starts at $s=0$ because it is not stated. That constant is the initial position so you are free to say where it starts in your coordinate system.

Comment: Ok! So is the rest of my attempt correct? Or is there also an other way to solve that? @JohnDouma

Comment: It looks good to me. I didn't duplicate your calculations so I don't know if your numbers are correct but your methodology is.

Comment: Great!! And the path that we want t calculate is $s(25)-s(0)$, right? @JohnDouma

Comment: It's not necessary to assume $s(0) = 0$. You're correct that the length of the path is $s(25) - s(0)$, and in this case the constant $c$ cancels out, so there is no need to compute it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if $a$ is a linear function of $t$ then it is of the form:
$$a(t)=jt+a_0$$
since $a(0)=0$ we can see that $a_0=0$ now subbing in the value for $t=25$ we get:
$$a(25)=2.4=j\times 25$$ and so:
$$j=\frac{2.4}{25}=0.096$$
so:
$$a(t)=0.096t$$
So far all of this agrees with what you have said

---

now we know that:
$$v=\int a\,dt=0.048t^2+v_0$$
since $v(0)=0=v_0$ we can say that:
$$v(t)=0.048t^2$$
all good again

---

Now as for the displacement for $t\in[0,25]$ we can just say:
$$s(25)-s(0)=\int_0^{25}0.048t^2\,dt$$
so you do not need to work out an integration constant as it can be written as a definite integral, you got most of the way there :)

Comment: Thank you very much!! :-)